# How to write a test case for componentWillReceiveProps in my code using React

Tags: reactjs

This my code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.commentChanged(nextProps);
        if (nextProps.isOpen !== this.state.isOpen) {
            this.setState({
                disableCancel: nextProps.commentRequired,
                isOpen: nextProps.isOpen
            });
        }
    }
    commentChanged(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.value !== this.state.comment) {
            this.setState({
                comment: nextProps.value || ''
            });
        }
    }
```

Please help me write a test case for this.I have to cover if and else statement both while writing the test case.

Answer (score 0):

you can test your `componentWillReceiveProps` like this:

```
import ComponentName from ‘./ComponentName’;
import { shallow } from ‘enzyme’;
describe('componentWillReceiveProps()', () => {
    it('call commentChanged once', () => {
        const fakeCommentChanged =
        jest.spyOn(ComponentName.prototype, ‘commentChanged’);
        let defaultProps={isOpen:false}//define your props here
        const component = shallow(<ComponentName props={defaultProps}/>;
        changedProps={isopen:true}//define your nextProps here
        // triggers componentWillReceiveProps
        component.setProps(changedProps);
        //expectations
        expect(fakeCommentChanged).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
       //write more expectations for other checks like when nextProps.value!=this.state.comment
    })
})
```

we can help you with that `if-else` conditions If only we know your component state structure and props structure